# prove $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}$

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory

Prove:

$$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}$$

**My attempt:**

Let $$I=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx$$

Then:

$$I^2=\left(\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx\right)\left(\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dy\right)$$

Moreover,

$$I^2=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-(x^2+y^2)}{2}}dx\right)dy$$

Here i'm stuck, with the integration region using polar coordinates, can someone help me?

Comment: In polar $x^2+y^2=R^2$ and $dxdy=RdR d \theta$.

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what you want to do. If you switch to polar coordinates, then you'll get that $$I^2=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}\, dxdy=\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^\infty e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}r\, drd\theta=2\pi,$$ by a simple $u$-substitution. Now, you can take the square root to conclude.

To elaborate more on the region of integration, integrating on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the same as integrating on a disk of radius $r$ and taking $r\rightarrow\infty.$ That's what the integral limits correspond to.